# Custom add to cart button, if the customer has bought previously the product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In WooCommerce, I need to know if there's any option to change the add to cart button, if the customer has bought previously the product.

We're selling online courses via WooCommerce & Membership, so the idea is that if the customer hasn't bought the course, he has to see the "Shop now" button. But if he has bought the course, he should see a "View now" button, with a custom link for each product (course).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully functional and tested custom function that will display on shop pages and archives woocommerce pages, a custom add-to-cart (text + link), for logged in customers that have already bought the products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'customizing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function customizing_add_to_cart_button( $link, $product ){

    $bought = false;

    if( is_user_logged_in() ){

        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
        ) );

        // Going through each current customer orders
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
            // Going through each current customer order items
            foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
                if($item_values['product_id'] == $product->id){
                    $bought = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($bought){

        // ==> SET HERE YOUR
        // CUSTOM ADD TO CART text and link
        $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/custom_link/');
        $button_text =  __('View now', 'woocommerce');

    } else {

        $add_to_cart_url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
        $button_text =  $product->add_to_cart_text();

    }

    $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $add_to_cart_url ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $button_text )
    );

    return $link;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

If you want to customize the add-to-cart button for some specific products, or an array of products or a product category, you will have to add a condition by specific product, this way (this is an extract of the code above):

```
    if($bought){

        // for the product ID 45 (for example)
        if( $product->id == 45 ){
            $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/custom-link/product-45/');
            $button_text =  __('View now product 45', 'woocommerce');
        }

        // for the product ID 64 (for example)
        if( $product->id == 64){
            $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/custom-link/product-64/');
            $button_text =  __('View now product 64', 'woocommerce');
        }

        // for an array of product IDs (for example)
        $product_ids = array(89, 92, 124);
        if( in_array( $product->id, $product_ids ) ){
            $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/custom-link/some-products/');
            $button_text =  __('View now some products', 'woocommerce');
        }
        // for a product category
        // set here your product category ID, slug or name (or an array of values)
        $category = 'My category'; // Here a category name for example
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product->id ) ){
            $add_to_cart_url = site_url('/custom-link/my-category/');
            $button_text =  __('View now from my category', 'woocommerce');
        }
    } else {

        $add_to_cart_url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
        $button_text =  $product->add_to_cart_text();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution add it to functions.php and should work. When order will be complete button will be changed.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','add_to_cart_link_customer_has_bought');

    function add_to_cart_link_customer_has_bought() {

        global $product;

        if( empty( $product->id ) ){

            $wc_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
            $product = $wc_pf->get_product( $id );

        }

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id ) ){

            $product_url = get_permalink();
            $button_label =  "View Product";  

        } else {

            $product_url =  $product->add_to_cart_url();  
            $button_label = $product->add_to_cart_text();

        };

        echo sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product_url ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            esc_html( $button_label )
        );

    }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!! And another question, once using this code, where can I change the url that should have to redirect the button? Is it possible to set a different link for each product, and how can I do it?

Comment: What link? where it should go ? Link you can place here `esc_url( $product_url )` but we must know what link it be?