# Change "add to cart" text if a user has bought specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I wanted to know if there is a way to replace the woo-commerce "add to cart" button with custom text and url for a specific product **if the user has bought that specific product.**

and I want it happens everywhere (on shop page,product page , ...)

Comment: _"if the user has bought that specific product."_ 
In a previous order or the current one? 
What have you tried so far?

Comment: @7uc1f3r  In a previous order , I have only a function to check if the user has bought a product.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following that will change the product "add to cart" text if that product has already been bought by the customer on single product pages and archive pages

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text', 900, 2 ); // Archive product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text', 900, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_text( $button_text, $product ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $button_text = __("Custom text", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

Now you can also **restrict that to specific product ids** like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text', 900, 2 ); // Archive product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text', 900, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button_text, $product ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // HERE define your specific product IDs in this array
    $specific_ids = array(37, 40, 53);

    if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) 
    && in_array( $product->get_id(), $specific_ids ) ) {
        $button_text = __("Custom text", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). it should work.

Some [related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754%20has%20bought) threads:

- [Change "add to cart" button for purchased products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358312/change-add-to-cart-button-for-purchased-products-in-woocommerce/52359143#52359143)
- [Custom add to cart button, if the customer has bought previously the product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684374/custom-add-to-cart-button-if-the-customer-has-bought-previously-the-product/41697299#41697299)
- [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/38875458#38875458)